# How to use a Pytorch-based neural network in openfoam?

Tags: neural-network, openfoam

Could someone please explain me how to use a Pytorch-based neural network in CFD calculations using openFOAM?
I am a total newbie and could not find a good explanation and have no idea how to get started with that.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about using the pytorch C++ API in OpenFOAM https://tmaric.gitlab.io/, in the next one I'll describe how to train the networks with field data.